# iOS: best practice for database communication

Tags: ios, swift

I use the MVC Architecture in Xcode. I store all my View Files in the View Package, the Controller Classes in the Controller package and the Model classes in the model package.

However I want to create some sort of "services".

I have some experience in angular where services are classes which communicate with databases. In my case a firebase database. You have one instance of the service and you can inject this instance into the controller. So you can for example in one controller call `getStudents()` and store them in some sort of list and then in another controller you can access this list and display it.

In tutorials I saw that they communicate with the database inside the ViewController, but I think that is bad architecture. I want to use the same principle of services in Xcode because I don't want to handle fetching and retrieving data inside the controller.

How is this done in Xcode? Are there any best practices?

Comment: I see what you are asking. However, this question will only result in opinions. There is no singular **right** way.

Answer (score -1):

You can follow MVVM architecture or VIPER architecture in iOS which will help you keep your viewcontroller leaner and your code modularized ,re-usable and unit-testable.